# Doing arithmetic on the results of a MySQL select command

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database with temperatures stored in Centigrade.  Assuming my select command is:

```
Select Temp1, temp2, temp3 from TableA where ....
```

Is there a way in the Select statement to convert the output to Fahrenheit, ie report Temp1*9/5+32 instead of Temp1?

Thanks....RDK

Comment: Temp1*9/5+32 - Is exactly how you would do it - did you have a problem trying this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way in the Select statement to convert the output to Fahrenheit, ie report Temp1*9/5+32 instead of Temp1?

Yes. It's about as easy as it looks. How about this?

```
SELECT (Temp1 * 9.0 / 5.0) + 32.0 TempF
```

Or to avoid messy long decimal numbers in the result, this.

```
SELECT ROUND((Temp1 * 9.0 / 5.0) + 32.0, 1) TempF
```

Comment: Yes!!! this works from a SSH session on my Raspberry Pi.  However :-(, when I use that exact command from  my Python program, it throws this error "SQL error  '(Temp_Kitchen * 9.0 / 5.0) + 32.0 as Kitchen'".  Any ideas.

Comment: The Python program is using the pymysql  and mysql.connector routines to interface with the MariaDB database.

Comment: I fixed the program issue.  Again, thanks for the quick and simple answer